# Openlayers 6.9.0, cannot to create a production bundle

Tags: openlayers

When following the instructions on
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/tutorials/bundle.html
it is not possible to create a functional production bundle.
The developed application appears at http: // localhost: 3000 / not at http: // localhost: 1234 /, as it is written.
A bundle that is created using "npm run build" is broken.

Answer (score 1):

The default bundler used by create-ol-app was recently changed from Parcel to Vite.

Vite by default assumes the project will be placed at the web server root and uses an absolute base path (path starts with a `/`)
This can be configured in `vite.config.js` with the `base` config option. To use a relative path this should be

```js
export default {
  base: './',
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
  }
}
```

See https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/docs/config/index.md#base

The port change will be correctly documented once https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/12899 is merged.

Comment: Thanks, Vite looks better than Parcel. However, I still can't generate the production bundle.
I've tried all the ways to define the path in vite.config.js, but I'm still failing.
Thank you for the advice.

Comment: If you need help with this you need to provide more information than it doesn't work. E. g. an error message. The updated instructions worked for me.

Comment: Everything is already working fine for me. The proposed modification of vite.config.js is really necessary. Thank you for the advice. JS.